# error in tagdirective

Tags: struts, taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/LIB/struts-html.tld" %>
```

Error displaying invalid taglib.. no setter method for the "name " in tld.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ver much unclear but from whqat I see is that your path is incorrect, the `LIB` should be changed to `lib`. Also, you need to `prefix` your taglib.

Change this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/LIB/struts-html.tld" %>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
```

Did you declare your TLD in web.xml?

**PS** If you have your Struts jars (including taglib jars) then you can just do this in jsp's.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
```